# Angular 2+ routing change from outside of context

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, electron, angular2-routing

I have problem with routing in Angular 2+ app, which is built with Electronjs. Communication between angular and electron based on async events. I try to change route of angular app on one of these async callbacks from electron and I get situation where new component from new route is loaded but old component from old route also is still visible and currrent route is still set as old route. This is both in standard angular router and in ui router. 
Why route cannot be changed proper? This is problem with changeing route from outside of angular app?
Is there any way to notify angular about route change?

Comment: it's look like this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629987/changes-dont-propagate-through-the-component. just put in ngZone.run(()=>router.navigation([path])

Comment: cool, it was that, thanks