# Callback function changes do not affect UI

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Angular 5.2.0 and TypeScript 2.6.2.

I'm using the [following plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nfc) to read NFC tags. The listener starts when user presses button.

```
<button (tap)="doStartNdefListener()" text="Get NFC"></button>
<Label [text]="nfcText" textWrap="true"></Label>
```

**The problem** - even though the callback in **doStartNdefListener()** successfully scans for tag, saves the output in **nfcText**, outputs values from within callback, even though the value for **nfcText** has been changed, it does not update the UI.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Nfc, NfcTagData, NfcNdefData } from "nativescript-nfc";

export class StartComponent { 
public nfc: Nfc;
public nfcText: string;

constructor(){
    this.nfc = new Nfc();
}

public doStartNdefListener() {
    this.nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener((data: NfcNdefData) => {
        if (data.message) {
            let tagMessages = [];
                data.message.forEach(record => { 
                    tagMessages.push(record.payloadAsString); });

                console.log(tagMessages.join(", "));
                this.nfcText = tagMessages.join(", ");
                console.log(this.nfcText);
            }
        },
        { stopAfterFirstRead: true, scanHint: "Scan the tag!" })
        .then(() => this.nfcText = "Listening for tag")
        .catch(err => alert(err));
    }
}
```

Both console outputs print out the scanned NFC tag value, but the label does not get updated.

Edit:

What is interesting is that UI updates after I execute another function after I've ran doStartNdefListener() function.

Comment: You can try the 3 methods suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/1009922).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@rgantla, the problem is that Angular don´t take acount the change (don't refresh the labels). So, make a function

```
private changeNfcText (message:string) {
            this.ngZone.run(()=>{
              this.nfcText = message;
             });
        }
    }
```

Then,

```
this.nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener((data: NfcNdefData) => {
        if (data.message) {
            let tagMessages = [];
                data.message.forEach(record => { 
                    tagMessages.push(record.payloadAsString); });

                console.log(tagMessages.join(", "));
                this.changeNfcText(tagMessages.join(", ")); //<--call the function
                console.log(this.nfcText);
            }
        },
        { stopAfterFirstRead: true, scanHint: "Scan the tag!" })
        .then(() => this.changeNfcText("Listening for tag")) //<--call the function
        .catch(err => alert(err));
    }
```

Comment: This is correct answer. The correct NfcText function is the following: private changeNfcText(message: string) { this.ngZone.run(() => { this.nfcText = message; }) }

Comment: I've update the answer with your correction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below approach?

```
<Label> {{nfcText}} </Label>
```

I cannot recall if there exists a text property on the label that you can bind to, but surely, you can use string interpolation to output your text to the view.

Comment: It's looks like a similar problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629987/changes-dont-propagate-through-the-component

Comment: @Eliseo, but, in his question he mentioned that he is able to console.log(this.nfcText). So, i'm not really sure if the "this" keyword has to be bound and is out of scope of this particular class

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping that into a $timeout block.

```
$timeout(()=> {
     this.nfcText = tagMessages.join(", ");
}, 100);
```

This will force a digest cycle that will make your UI notice the change.